# Quick file loading in C#

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to load a file containing up to 1 million lines of string data. My first thought is to use C# 5.0 async to load the data whilst not blocking the UI thread. If the user tries to access something that relies on the data they will get a loading message.

Still I would like the fastest possible method in order to improve the user's experience.

Is the speed of reading data from the disk purely a function of the disk speed and thus StreamReader.ReadAllLines() is as performant as other c# code? Or is there something 'fancy' I can do to boost performance programmatically. This does not have to be described in detail. If so what approximate percentage improvement might be achieved?

I am purely interested in read speed and not concerned with the speed of code that may process the data once loaded.

Comment: It depends upon what you're going to do with that 1 million lines. What you're trying to achieve after loading the file?

Comment: Loading files quicker requires a faster disk, not faster code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, take a look on File size, here is detailed [Performance measurements](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0502012.pdf)